# Creating Workflow Custom Action on SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a requirement which is not OOTB. We are planning to create Workflow custom action using VS. Any head start on this is highly appreciated. We don't have SharePoint Foundation/Server installed on our machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create sandbox workflow action by this reference link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798499.aspx

Sandbox solution may be run directly on SharePoint online.

Comment: post the code instead a link.. it will be helpful if link no more available

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does this need installation of SP Server or SP Foundation? Right now I dont have anything related to SP on my machine. We are using the sharepoint site only with OOTB features

Comment: At first, try simple workflow with office 365 trial account. If it is working, no need to install SP server.

Comment: @VirajGorajia, Is there any other methods apart from using O365? Do we need to purchase SP Server to develop solutions for SP Online? Kindly clarify

Comment: Try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/418cccd0-00ac-4460-b608-7c0910a41a2d/build-sandbox-solution-without-a-sharepoint-server?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious